# Redirect Vim output to file

Tags: vim, neovim

I used to be able to do this, but how do I direct the output of a file open in vim to a different file? I used to redirect the output of a python script open in vim to the TTY of a different terminal so I could see the output of the script without having to switch windows. Please show me how to do this again!

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be separated into 3 parts:

1. Running an external command inside Vim
2. Redirecting output of the command
3. Using other terminals as a redirection target

https://superuser.com/questions/285500/how-to-run-unix-commands-from-within-vim
You can run an external command in Vim command line by prefixing it with `!`.  Since '`%`' is an alias for the name of the current buffer, `:!python %` is all you need to execute the current Python script you're editing.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html
Redirecting the output can be done with `>` operator. `:!python % > output.txt` will write the output of current Python script into `output.txt`.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270273/393602
To write the output to a different terminal rather than files, you need to figure out the TTY device of the output terminal. After that, you can just use that device as redirection target (e.g. `:!python % > /dev/pty/3`).

As a side note, there are a bunch of plugins that can automate executing the current file/project and viewing output in a scratch buffers. If you don't like plugins, it's also not that hard to [write your own script](https://youtu.be/9gUatBHuXE0) to do this. I'd probably prefer using these automation tools than having to set up TTY redirection every time.